Prove the Borel Algebra is Generated with Open Half-lines
I'm very unsure about my answer for exercise I'm doing. Here is the exercise:
Show that if $\mathcal{H} = \mathbb{R}$ then the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the collection of open half-lines $(a, \infty)$ where $a \in \mathbb{Q}$.
And here is my attempt at an answer:
We know that the Borel algebra $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ is generated by the collection $\mathcal{U}$ of all open subsets $(a,b)$ of $\mathbb{R}$ (assuming the usual topology). We would like to show that $\mathcal{U}$ can be constructed, using countable unions and set differences, from the collection of all open half-lines, which would imply that $\mathcal{U}$ also generates $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$. Any left open set $(a, b]$ can be written as $
(a, b] = (a, \infty) \setminus (b, \infty)$
So we can write any open interval as a countable union
$
(a, b) = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (a, b - \frac{1}{n}]$.
I'm fairly certain my answer is wrong since $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ so I've really only showed that we can construct open intervals with rational numbers, but aside from that I'm not sure my reasoning is correct here. To show that the Borel algebra is generated by open half-lines do I need to do more than just show every open interval can be constructed from the set of open half-lines using the properties of $\sigma$-algebras?
Any guidance on either issue is much appreciated!

Let $a<b$. $(a,b)=\bigcup ((r_n,s_n)$ where $r_n,s_n$ are rationals, $r_n$ decreases to $a$ and $s_n$ increases to $b$.

@geetha290krm Right! Thank you!
